# Check if the list is sorted

Tags: prolog

I am trying to find out a way to check whether a list is sorted from more to less. I found a way to check it in a proper way with following rules.

```
ordered( []      ) .
ordered( [_]     ) .
ordered( [X,Y|Z] ) :- X =< Y , ordered( [Y|Z] ) .
```

However, what I want to do is not that simple. Here is my database.

```
%travelto(Traveler,Traveling_to,Distance,Cost).
travelto(lyla,josh,300,45).
travelto(martin,john,250,55).
travelto(leo,najma,100,20).
travelto(diana,kyle,230,15).
travelto(michael,lucy,90,15).
travelto(sam,kate,300,40).
travelto(jason,cindy,170,26).
travelto(julia,nayma,110,10).
```

I want to type a list of Traveler in query and check wheter the list is sorted from more to less or not by Cost. I want prolog to return true if the list is sorted or false if it is not. I tried my best and still haven't got the answer. Can someone please help me?

```
?- checkOrder([martin,lyla,michael,julia]). %example of query I want to type in prolog
true. %return I am expecting from above query

?- checkOrder([martin,lyla,michael,sam]). %example of query I want to type in prolog
false. %return I am expecting from above query
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the costs list, then reuse your code:

```
checkOrder(Persons) :-
  findall(C, (member(P,Persons), travelto(P,_,_,C)), Costs),
  ordered(Costs).
```

but a change to ordered/1 is required, because right now it checks for ascending sort:

```
...  :- X >= Y , ...
```

Otherwise, reverse/2 Costs before ordered/1

Or, just to illustrate an alternative (ordered/1 not required):

```
checkOrder(Persons) :-
  forall(append(_, [P,Q|_], Persons), (
    travelto(P,_,_,C), travelto(Q,_,_,D), C >= D
  )).
```